# How to reorder ToolStrip items in code

Tags: c#

How do you programatically reorder items on a ToolStrip in C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I have found a way around this by using the Insert() method of the Items collection and specifying the index i want the item at.

i.e.

```
toolStrip1.Items.Insert(0, myButton);
```